# What's up with answering questions with questions in this joke from Family Guy?

Tags: popular-culture, humor

From Family Guy [S12E12](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=36Oxbur_OAY)

(Outside synagogue)

> Stewie: So, where do they think they go when they die?
>
> Brian: Well, you should try asking the rabbi. Although, I should warn
> you, you might not get an answer.

(Inside synagogue with rabbi)

> Stewie: So, where do Jewish people think they go when they die?
>
> Rabbi: Where do you think we go?
>
> Stewie: Well, I don't know. That's why I'm asking you.
>
> Rabbi: Why do you think you're asking all these questions?
>
> Stewie: I-I just, I just really want to know what happens.
>
> Rabbi: Do you think that's part of God's infinite plan?
>
> Stewie: I think your whole religion is a sham, just so you can get
> extra holidays off from work.
>
> Rabbi: Oop, gotta go. It's [Buchwuch](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=buchwuch).

I think I get the joke of the last 2 lines, but before that, the rabbi answers Stewie's questions with questions. Lots of religious, theological or philosophical professionals do this even if they're atheists or agnostics. Is this seeming stereotype about Jews or rabbis somehow based on Judaism?

---

Asked on meta: [Are questions on jokes, humour or pop culture allowed?](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5355/are-questions-on-jokes-humour-or-pop-culture-allowed)

Comment: @mbloch Edited post based on meta: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5355/are-questions-on-jokes-humour-or-pop-culture-allowed/5356?noredirect=1#comment16922_5356

Comment: "Responding to questions with questions" does two good things : [1.] It satisfies the inquirer, because people like knowing they have been heard. [2.] It filters out unnecessary data in order to return the answer the inquirer needs.

Comment: @חִידָה Is responding to questions with questions better at accomplishing those goals than responding to questions with answers?

Comment: @DoubleAA LOL XD

Comment: @DoubleAA 1 - can the deleted just answer just be cw instead? 2 - is it acceptable for an answer to this to be phrased in the form of questions? i mean imagine like a serious credible unbiased good answer normally written and then change all the statements to questions

Comment: @חִידָה I FINALLY FOUND A SOURCE I THINK? May you please see my post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after 3.5 years I think I found it? Is this what Wikipedia says?

> A common stereotype is that the Jews answer a question with a question. It is used in Jewish humor and in ordinary literature when it is required to paint a character as a "typical Jew".

Is this the source that Wikipedia cites?

[Jews Love Questions March 3, 2011 | by Marnie Winston-Macauley](https://aish.com/jews_love_questions/)

Comment: Mazel tov, BCLC. I have not clicked on your source, but it's a well-known trope that Jews like to answer questions with questions. Or, in this case, answers with answers ;)

Comment: @יהושעק LOL thanks. Edit: Todah I guess

Comment: The question was "Is this seeming stereotype about Jews or rabbis somehow based on Judaism?" I'm not sure how this answers the question.

Comment: @DoubleAA Negatively? Or idk. Devil's proof otherwise.